# Google maps polygon not updating color after setOptions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

I'm using the Google Maps API alongside AngularJS. I have the following function to change a polygon's color using `setOptions`:

```
desk.modColor = function (color) {
     desk.setOptions({ fillColor: color });
}
```

I'm calling it from within angularJS with code like the following:

```
$scope.focusedDesk.modColor('#0592fa');
```

However, this is only working about 75% of the time. After enough scope manipulation in AngularJS, this stops working. If I `console.log` the `desk` object immediately after the `modColor` call, it has the correct `fillColor`, but the polygon on the map hasn't updated visually.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there any way to ensure that `setOptions` updates the Map/Polygon visually? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with the code I was using to change the polygon colors. Some of my other code was duplicating polygons, and so they would stack and the highlighted polygon would be hidden by the newer duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

### condition 1

if you are manipulating you DOM in any form within angularJS you should probably use directives
in this case you should write a directive to do that for you:

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('myDirective',function(){
   return {
      scope: { focusedDesk:'=' },
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
               scope.$watch('your-whatever-object-or-property-you-want-to-watch-over', function(){
                                   //your desired action
                              })
            }
   }
})
```

and the usage would be something like this:

```
<div my-directive focusedDesk='focusedDesk'></div>
```

### condition 2

if you are just concerned about the property's value you could `$scope.$watch` the same as above in your `controller` function

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to ensure that setOptions updates the Map/Polygon
>   visually?

Yes, call

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {$scope.$apply();}
```